# AES Encryption/Decryption of docx and pdf files not working

Tags: powershell, encryption, aes, pfx

I have a piece of Powershell script that successfully encrypts and decrypts text files, but it doesn't seem to work with .docx or .pdf files, or even jpegs that matter.

```
$newcert="cert-test"
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName $newcert -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My" -KeyUsage KeyEncipherment,DataEncipherment,KeyAgreement -Type DocumentEncryptionCert -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddDays(30)  -FriendlyName $newcert
$cert=Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\CurrentUser\My\ | Where-Object subject -like "*$newcert*"
$thumb=$cert.thumbprint
$file = "d:\target\test\Test.pdf"
# protect
Get-Content $file | Protect-CmsMessage -To $thumb -OutFile $file

#unprotect
Unprotect-cmsmessage -LiteralPath $file -To $thumb
```

The end result are files that are clearly corrupted.

Comment: "The end result are files that are clearly corrupted." - how did you determine this?

Comment: Uhhhh, because they don't open. Jpegs are just smears of colors.

Comment: There must be something missing from your code - how are you writing the output from `Unprotect-CmsMessage` to disk?

Comment: I tried Set-Content $file but that didn't seem to work, either.

Answer (score 1):

`Protect-CmsMessage` can only encrypt text. Curruption for other file types is expected.

A possible workaround is to Base64 encode your files before encrypting it.

```
$File = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes('C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe')
$Base64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($File)
$Base64 | Protect-CmsMessage -To $thumb | Out-File -FilePath $env:TEMP\encrypted.txt
```

Keep in mind, that the receiver has to decode the Base64 string.

```
$Base64 = Get-Content -Path $env:TEMP\encrypted.txt | Unprotect-CmsMessage -To $thumb
$ByteStream = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($Base64)
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("$env:TEMP\calc.exe", $ByteStream)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that shot.

Comment: Thanks, again. This is a big help.